# Copy a field from Access to use in another access object

Tags: ms-access

I have a form that uses a query to open and display a specific customer info based on a customer ID that is manually entered by the user.

The form populates with the customer info from a table where the customer ID can only occur one time.  A sub form opens below the customer info with a list of items owned by that customer from another table where the customer ID can occur many times but the items owned is limited by a unique Serial Number.

I have this form set to No Edits so someone does not hose up the original data.

I would like for the user to select a particular Owned Item / Serial Number, and have that SN copied and used to automatically populate another query to open a new work request on that SN.

I don't know if this is possible or not but if so some help with the code or macro would be most helpful.

I understand that using Ctrl C and Ctrl V are the simple answer but the people using this don't want the extra effort and in some cases it is beyond them to even that right.

Comment: Can have code in textbox Click event that sets value of a global variable or a TempVars variable which can then be used in other procedures. A query can reference a TempVars variable or call a custom function. There are many ways to accomplish passing a value to other elements of database, but copying to clipboard is the last option I would consider. Your question is really too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Create a buttom in the subform and write there a code to start a new record with the same serial as the current record in the subform